# Dynamically change a table name in an index/match formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this formula

```
=INDEX(SalesData18[[Prod1]:[Prod12]],MATCH($B$16,SalesData18[Name],0),MATCH(A17,SalesData18[[#Headers],[Prod1]:[Prod12]],0))
```

Is there a way to dynamically change the name from `SalesData18` to `SalesData19` without using `indirect()`? I am not sure if there is a way to do this by using a helper column? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is problem with `indirect()`? Show some sample data and your expected output. May be there are something better than what you are thinking.

Comment: I am using the data set from this link https://excel-bytes.com/how-to-use-index-and-match-in-a-table-with-indirect-in-excel/ . I wanted to see if there was another method aside from indirect because everyone I speak to discourages its use. I am also not sure how to implement it into the above formula if there is more than one table. I want to do something similar in regards to a drop down where the index/match will search the 19 table if that is selected.

Comment: In your case to change table name I think only way to use `Infirect()`.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to implement it into the formula? I was thinking of some sort of helper cell, but the indirect turns the cell value into a text string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `INDIRECT(cell_reference & "[column_name]")` where the cell with address of cell_reference contains a table name.